# Angular Material Autocomplete - Listen to keyup event

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material

I have a mat autocomplete field that works normally (I can search results, scroll and click or press enter on an item to select it).

Now I want to add the ability to listen to keyup events when typing in the input field, but this is not working.

The reason for this is, I want the user to be able to select from a list of existing values, or hit enter to add a custom value, here is my code:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [matAutocomplete]="tagsAutocomplete" formControlName="tagsInput">
</mat-form-field>

<mat-autocomplete #tagsAutocomplete="matAutocomplete" 
                  (optionSelected)="addTag($event)" 
                  (keyup.enter)="addTag($event)">
    
    <mat-option *ngIf="isLoading" class="is-loading">
        <mat-spinner diameter="50"></mat-spinner>
    </mat-option>

    <ng-container *ngIf="!isLoading">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let tag of tags" [value]="tag">
            <span>{{ tag }}</span>
        </mat-option>
    </ng-container>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

The above keyup event however, is no t triggering at all.

Comment: You should try adding the event handler on the input instead.